# Wrong filenames timestamp listing in .txt file after comparison with the creation date

Tags: shell, files, text

*This is a part of my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451746/filenames-correction-of-timestamp-with-correct-creation-date) about filenames timestamps correction, i wanted to separate it from the other question so that maybe some of the community member will not have a hard time to find it,*

I have a big number of image files spared in many folders under a base directory, and some of the files got a filename with the wrong timestamp, so what i want is to compare the filename timestamp with the creation date of each file and generate a `.txt` file listing the wrong filenames only.

You can find here an example: 
**Original filename with false timestamp:**
Filename, Created Date, Modified Date
20180524010500530_FR785101.jpg, 2018-05-24 00:05:00, 2018-05-24 00:05:34

**The correct filename with correct timestamp is:**
 
Filename, Created Date, Modified Date
20180524000500530_FR785101.jpg, 2018-05-24 00:05:00, 2018-05-24 00:05:34

I started using `ls -lc` and `stat` to get the creation time but i still couldn't figure out how i can compare between the filename timestamp and the creation date and generate a `.txt` listing all the wrong filenames.

So, is there anyone that can help me write a shell script that can do the job ?

Comment: `ls -c` does not show _creation_ time.  It shows the timestamp of the last _change_ to the inode.

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Kusalananda but you could at least vote up so that it will be visible for community members that can help

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the header that it is a part from the previous question. It is for making it more visible and easy to find for community members and maybe for people visiting this `stackexchange` in general

Comment: It is not, maybe if you take a look at the previous question, you will make the difference...and maybe you can bring a solution to the question instead of blocking it, right ?!

Comment: @Kusalananda done ! i hope it makes sense for you now ! otherwise do not hesitate to suggest more so that the question can reach out people that can help

Comment: I edited the other post to remove the part that's covered by this question, and reopened this one